# Laravel: Prevent direct access of files from public folder

Tags: php, .htaccess, laravel-5

I am stuck on this part of my laravel application, Where I am asked to protect the files from directly accessed via url browser hit.
I have a public folder in which in a doc folder is present where all the documents are going to be uploaded. I just need a solution to prevent this where i can access docs directly from my application but any third party visitor can not view my docs (images,pdfs etc..).

I have tried many solutions but its not at all working.
I just want to things :-
1. Protect my docs through direct access.
2. Way of implementing it in laravel (via .htaccess)

I know this can be possible through htaccess, but how?
Kindly help Please :)

Answer (score 4):

Add in your upload folder `.htaccess` file with content:

```
Deny from  all
```

Answer (score 4):

There are three approaches I can think of just now;

1. You intercept all image and video requests with Laravel, then using the router, serve up the content that the user was after, provided they are authorised. THIS WILL BE SLOW!.
2. You rely on obscurity and put all that clients images, videos etc in a folder that has a long-unguessable random url. You can then link to the content in your code using the 'static' folder name. The customer's content will always be in that folder and accessible if they log in or not. The advantage of this compared to 1 is that your framework does not have to boot for every image or video.
3. Have all the content hidden away - possibly in the storage folder. When the user logs in, create a temporary symbolic link between their public folder and their folder in storage. Keep a note of the link in the session. Use the link in all gallery etc rather than the static code used in (2) above. Once they log out the code will no longer be valid, and you can delete the symbolic link on logout or have a job to tidy it up periodically.